# how to fix mobile portable devices elements are not working touch?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, html, css, mobile-devices

I am using bootstrap framework, angular js, node js to develop an application I am trying to apply some css on hover(on touch on mobile). it is  not working in the real device. how to solve any one help me

Answer (score 0):

Use the `:focus` pseudo class as well, on the elements you are already using `:hover` on.

```
.class:hover,
.class:focus {
    /* insert hover style rules here */
}
```

This should give you the desired effect on mobile.